# uWSGI + Django + Python: no module named uwsgi

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am trying to setup uwsgi for my Django project.
It runs fine with

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9010
```

But when I try

```
 uwsgi --http :9010 --chdir /home/user/appname --module wsgi --wsgi-file /home/user/appname/appname/wsgi.py
```

I get

```
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Here is the full log:

```
uWSGI http bound on :9010 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 1900)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:42684 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
Python version: 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 13:01:26)  [GCC 4.9.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1c17310
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
ImportError: No module named wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robert/surmaroute/surmaroute/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 1899, cores: 1)
```

Comment: This is causing an issue because apparently your app doesn't have a module `wsgi`. This is the module that uwsgi is attempting to import to find your app. Based on the structure above, you may want something like `--module appname.wsgi` but you may not even need that since you have `--wsgi-file` specified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that your app does not have a module named `uwsgi`. You change the directory to `/home/user/appname` but it looks like the actual module would be `appname.uwsgi` since the `uwsgi.py` file lives within `/home/user/appname/appname/uwsgi.py`.

Typically though, you don't need to specify both `--wsgi-file` and `--module` so I would either do

```
uwsgi --http :9010 --chdir /home/user/appname --wsgi-file /home/user/appname/appname/wsgi.py
```

or

```
uwsgi --http :9010 --chdir /home/user/appname --module appname.uwsgi
```

I personally prefer the second.